# Go thru each CSS value in a HTMLElement, merge CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a loop so I can walk thru all the CSS properties that are defined in an element. My goal is to create a function that merge the style of two elements.

```
<span id="a1" style="font-family:verdana;">Hello</span>
<span id="a2" style="font-size:15;">World</span>​
```

And the JS function would look something like this:

```
function mergeStyle (obj,target){
    $.each(test.style.CSSStyleDeclaration,function(){ // This will not work?
       // Add to target
    })
    return;
};
```

​

Comment: what would you like to do with duplicate properties? does any of the two have a priority?

Comment: For what reason? The browser, internally, is going to separate the properties again anyway. Since there's no consistent rules for grouping properties in CSS, you'd have to merge them on a case-by-case basis every time.

Comment: Is it required only for inline styles?

Comment: Its a controlled environment so it will not happend. However for a more generic solution you maybe will have a overwrite argument that you also pass to the function

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Yes, I need only inline style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using classes instead, since your need doesn't sound as a good design. If you still want it though, this should work:

```
$.fn.mergeCSS = function(other) {
  var $this  = $(this),
      $other = $(other),
      style  = $other.get(0).style;

  $.each(style, function(i, name) {
    $this.css(name, style[name]);
  });

  return this;
};
```

The `.style` property of an element contains its styles; `CSSStyleDeclaration` is `.style`'s constructor which is not element-specific.

Usage:

```
$("<p style='color:green'>").mergeCSS("<p style='background-color:red'>");
// <p style='color: green; background-color: red; '>
```

It alters and returns the first element.

Comment: Oh that was a sweet one! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the most simplest form if you want to just apply the styles from a to b then you can try this.

```
function mergeStyle (obj,target){
    target.style.cssText = target.style.cssText + ";" + obj.style.cssText;
};
mergeStyle($('#a2')[0], $('#a1')[0]);
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rDdMu/1/

Comment: One caveat is that some browsers need a literal ';' between the two cssText strings:  target.style.cssText += ';'+ obj.style.cssText; Better browsers insert a semicolon at the end of the cssText string, but the repeat doesn't hurt them.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution, that works for me:

```
function mergeStyle (obj,target){
    for(var i = 0; i<obj.style.length; i++){
        var stylename = obj.style[i];
        if(target.style[stylename]=="")        
           target.style[obj.style[i]] = obj.style[stylename];
        };
    };
};
```

​